# Bundled dynamic library : keep looking in the usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, shared-libraries, dylib

I have put my dynamic library xxx.dylib inside the app Content/Frameworks/ directory. I am working with OSX, Xcode.

I have set the "Runpath Search Paths" to @loader_path/../Frameworks

I have set the "Dynamic Library Install Name" to @rpath/xxx.dylib

It compiles and link fine. But I keep having the execution error.
"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/xxx.dylib"

If I put the library in /usr/local/lib/ then it works fine.

How can I tell Xcode to look for it in the Content/Frameworks/ directory?
Thank you,
Baptiste

Comment: I assume your platform is OSX?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I woke up this morning thinking I haven't specified that.

Comment: Find the built app bundle in `DerivedData` and use `otool -l` on the executable to see how it's trying to load the library (also check the library is actually being copied correctly).  You might be able to fix the error using the settings with Xcode but more often than not you are required to use `install_name_tool` to fix the *install name* of the library after copying.  It's fiddly but there are questions about it on this site.

Comment: Thank you, it was useful. I added a post build script to use install_name_tool in the end. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following post build script, which fixed the *install name* of the library:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/xxx.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/xxx.dylib $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Contents/MacOS/your_executable_name
```